# MySQL to return records with a date/time of now minus 1 hour?

Tags: mysql, datetime

can anybody help with a MySQL command to try and select all records within a table with a date/time equal to or more than now - 1hour?

Now I'm not 100% sure that that is the best way of describing this.

I basically have records with a date/time field (e.g. 2019-07-13 13:00:00) and I want to perform a MySQL select to find all records with a date/time of one hour ago. This is to trigger a function one hour after an event.

I currently have this, but not sure if it is along the right lines at all:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table_name
WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) >= 'date_of_event'
AND 'status' = 'Scheduled';
```

Any thoughts would be great!

Comment: `>=` should be `<=`

Comment: And remove the single quotes around the column `date_of_event`.

Comment: ...and `status`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are very close. The most readable way, in my opinion, to write WHERE conditions involving date / times is:

```
 WHERE date_of_event >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Why? `>=` for date/time values means *on or after.* You need to be able to look at your query code and reason about it. That formulation clearly matches your specification:

> a date/time equal to or more than now - 1hour?

**But**: you say you want to trigger an event one hour after the time. That probably means you want to choose

> a date/time one hour or more ago, that is a date/time equal to or less than now - 1 hour.

That's what you have already. But I would rewrite it

```
WHERE date_of_event <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

`<=` means *on or before.*

**Pro tip** Avoid backticks unless your columns or tables have the same names as reserved words like `SELECT` or `GROUP`.  Avoid naming your columns or tables with reserved words. Backticks look so much like single-quotes that it's easy to get confused.

**Pro tip** date/time expressions with `=` in them almost never come up true, because the equality must be exact, down to the second or millisecond. So avoid conditions like `date_of_event = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`.

Comment: Great, thanks very much for this, the following looks to be working for me:

SELECT * FROM database.table_name WHERE `status` = 'Scheduled' AND date_of_event <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table_name
WHERE `date_of_event` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
AND `status` = 'Scheduled';
```

Note that you use backticks instead of single quotation marks on reserved words.

Comment: Not that there are any reserved words here

Comment: You are correct. Left the backticks there to show the correct use of them. One could choose not to use them.