# How to determine which records will expire one hour or less from now

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a where clause that can be used to retrieve records for  will expire one hour or less from now ?

Comment: `WHERE expire_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL to return records with a date/time of now minus 1 hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578211/mysql-to-return-records-with-a-date-time-of-now-minus-1-hour)